# Node.js, Express, EJS - Active class on current page in navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, navigation, ejs

I'd like to render a 'current' class on each of my navigation links depending on which page I'm on in my layout.ejs template.

Currently, my express controller index looks like this:

```
// About
exports.about = function(req, res) {
    res.render('content/about.ejs', {
        title: 'About'
    });
};
```

And in my layout.ejs I have the following, which I'd like be rendered dynamically.

```
<ul class="nav" id="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could include a `page_name: 'about'` in the `res.render` data and then in the template something like:

```
<li <% if (page_name === 'about') { %>class="current" <% } %> ><a href="/about">About</a></li>
```

I didn't test the syntax, but that's the gist.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed correct, including the syntax. Much appreciated. I don't have any voting power yet, so I'll just accepted the answer.

Comment: Any way to get `page_name` automatically from `app.get()`'s input?

Comment: `req.path` is probably the closest thing.  See [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path) for docs.  You could easily strip out the slashes from the path to get something close to the page_name.  But nested path names (eg `/about/fred`) wouldn't work quite right then.  You could probably change the slashes to underscores to create a convention where the underscored version of req.path (eg, `req.path.replace(/\//g, '_')`) represented a page name

Comment: Great answer, solved my issue as well for <select> option as conditionally selected

Comment: @thataustin  buts its removing existing class

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a variable to the page like this, and use a condition inside the class attribute.

```
<a
    class="nav-link <%= page_name === 'home' && 'active' %>"
    href="#"
>
    Home
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

@thataustin's answer is correct! but I lost the default class, so I found a way to keep the default class when it's not active.
Hope it helps someone someday

```
<li            
    <% if (page_name === 'about') { %>
        class="nav-item current"
        <%} else { %>
        class="nav-item"
        <% } %> >
    <a href="/about">About</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have passed an object `{navSelectTitle : "your-required-page-to-be-selected"}` while rendering each page in the main `app.js`. Then, you can create a list in your ejs template like following:

```
<% const navItems = ["home", "articles", "videos", "audios"] %>
```

Then, you can loop through the list and add a class to make the link appear selected. (Here, I have used the class `class="selected"` to make the link appear selected)

Also, since I need my home page to have the href as `href="/"` and not `<a href="/home"`, I have created a separate if statement for the case of "home" to accomodate this special case.

```
<% navItems.forEach(navlink => { %>
    <% if(navlink == navSelectTitle) { %>
        <% if (navlink == "home") {%>
            <li class="links selected"><a href="/"><%= navlink %></a></li>
        <% } else {%>
            <li class="links selected"><a href="/<%= navlink %>"><%= navlink %></a></li>
        <% } %>
                
    <% } else { %>
        <% if (navlink == "home") {%>
            <li class="links"><a href="/"><%= navlink %></a></li>
        <% } else {%>
            <li class="links"><a href="/<%= navlink %>"><%= navlink %></a></li>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
<% }) %>
```

The code logic goes as follows:

1. Loop through the list.
2. If the list item equals to the object value that you passed while rendering the page, then the `li` tag will have the `class="selected"`. If not, the else statement will create a normal link without the selected class.
3. To accomodate the case where the home link should have `href="/"`, there's a nested if-else statement inside the if statement for the said case.

NOTE: Using partial for the navigation bar can help dry your code and makes this logic a little convenient.

Answer (score 0):

**[update]** - It is also possible to use a ternary logical:

1. First: Allow access to any variable/data in your views by setting the "server.js" file like so:

`app.get('*', (req, res, next) => { res.locals = ({ req: req }); next(); });`

1. Second: then in your frontend, use this ternary syntax you link, ex.:

`<li class="nav-item <%- ( req.url.search('about') == 1 ? ' active ' : ' ' ) %> ">`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's terrible to add additional value like req.path when you render.
You will have to add that value every single time you render a page that has a navbar.

```
res.render('home', { path: req.path });
```

I simply use jquery to change the active nav item's class.
The code to change class will be included in a ejs file (template) which will be included by every page so there is no additional code at all when you render!

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="Home">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="Docs">Docs</a>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(`a[href=${window.location.pathname}`).addClass('active');
```

The ejs file included by other pages would look like this:

```
<script src="/javascripts/axios-1.6.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/moment-2.18.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(`a[href=${window.location.pathname}`).addClass('active');
</script>
```