# Bootstrap 4 + Handlebars Navbar: Active Class Not Switching On Nav-Items

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar here in a project of mine. There are a couple of links. Clicking them all leads to their corresponding page. The hover effects work as well. The only problem is that The "Home" tab stays active and the other tabs do not become active when clicked and taken to the corresponding page.

Code:

bsnavbar.handlebars(partial)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/scry">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/scry/about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="scry/report">Report an issue</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

head.handlebars(partial)

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

main.handlebars(layout)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {{>head}}
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{>bsnavbar}}
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        {{{body}}}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

router.js (incase it matters)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.status(200);
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.render("index");
});

router.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.status(200);
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.render("about")
});

router.get("/report", function(req, res){
    res.status(200);
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.render("report");
});

router.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.render("404");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `active` class is hardcoded in your template on home link, you need to set it dynamically. A similar question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052480/node-js-express-ejs-active-class-on-current-page-in-navigation

Comment: Well it actually works for some reason if my hrefs are "#"

Comment: They change nav link color on css `:focus` selector, maybe that gives you that impression. Try clicking anywhere else after clicking on the nav link and it should fade.

Comment: @dostu very right you are! I'll check this out and try to do the same thing in the link you provided except with handlebars.