# Why does ejs not permit if else statements when the darn variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to copy something relatively simple from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052480/node-js-express-ejs-active-class-on-current-page-in-navigation)

```
<div <% if (page_name === 'overview') { %> class="menu__menu-overviewPage menu" <% } %>  class="menu">
```

and on any other page other than overview, I get an error of `page_name is not defined`

Why are if/else statements in every other circumstance able to permit undefined, or not yet defined variables, except for in ejs? How am I supposed to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will always throw an error in this case.

There is a difference in result of variable being undefined and variable being not defined.

You haven't defined the variable beforehand so it cant compare to anything because it doesn't exists. It's an error, which is correct.